# Adding BLACKLISTED LINKS in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I was wondering if anyone could give me ideas on this question.

What url/name/address do I use to add a Balcklist entry in Mediawiki?

Background: I have a Mediawiki site and one of the extensions that I have installed is called "Popups" which displays a preview of a page when you hover over a link. I want to disable the popups for a few specific pages and heard one possible way was to add those links as "BLACKLISTED" in the index.js file of the extension folder. The section in the file where the "BLACKLISTED_LINKS" go is below.

For example my page url is "https://help.site.com/index.php/mypage"   - how would I code that in the list below?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks - GJ231

```
BLACKLISTED_LINKS = [
    '.extiw',
    '.image',
    '.new',
    '.internal',
    '.external',
    '.oo-ui-buttonedElement-button',
    '.cancelLink a'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you set the configuration variable `$wgPopupsPageDisabled` in `LocalSettings.php` as described at [the extension page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Popups#Configuration_options). Note the issues with caching after changing that variable.